# Compose one image over another

Tags: image-processing

I'm a newbie in image processing using Mathematica.

I'd like to compose an image $A$ over an image $B$ into an image *C* such that

$\quad C[i,j] = B[i,j]$, if $A[i,j]$ is white

$\quad C[i,j] = A[i,j]$, otherwise

It would work if I could do `Min` on each pixel:

$\quad C[i,j] = \min(A[i,j],B[i,j])$

but `Min` does not seem to work component-wise.

Perhaps I could turn white in $A$ into transparency and then compose over $B$. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you check the [Image Composition docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageComposition.html)?

Comment: @Öskå, I did but can't seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: You can use `ImageApply` to apply a function like `Min` pixel-wise. Or turn the images to normal arrays using `ImageData` and use `MapThread`.

Comment: Your comment to @Öskå suggests that you *have* tried something, which means you can post it here, which will help us help you.

Comment: @nikie, that worked, thanks! Perhaps you could add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Your two definitions of `C[i, j]` do not describe the same image operation. Which of the two operation do you really want to perform?

Comment: @m_goldberg You're right. I assumed the first one in my answer

Answer (score 8):

The naive method for component-wise `Min` is

```
img1 = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
img2 = ColorNegate[img1]
```

[image]

```
ImageApply[Min /@ Transpose@{##} &, {img1, img2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

But it is quite slow. However, one can note that
$$
\min(A,B) = \frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}-\left|\frac{A}{2}-\frac{B}{2}\right|
$$
Therefore, let's try the following

```
ImageSubtract[ImageAdd[##], ImageDifference[##]] &[
  ImageMultiply[img1, 0.5], ImageMultiply[img2, 0.5]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

It is much faster!

P.S. It is also faster then `ColorSeparate`/`ColorCombine`:

```
ColorCombine[ImageApply[Min, #] & /@ 
   Transpose[ColorSeparate /@ {img1, img2}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
(* Two sample images *)
a = Image[RandomReal[1, {100, 100, 3}]];
b = Image[Array[If[#1 < #2, RandomReal[.5, 3], {1, 1, 1}] &, {100, 100}]];

(* Calculate*)

Timing[
 mask = Binarize[b, {1., 1., 1.} == # &];
 c = ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[a, mask], ImageMultiply[b, ColorNegate@mask]];
 GraphicsRow[{a, b, mask, c}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]